# Using Thymeleaf to perform DOM manipulation when filling forms

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am  currently tasked with building an admin dashboard for a springboot backend API  ,  I have a few questions concerning this. need to understand if this use case is workable using thymeleaf templating engine.

I have 3 html select input boxes. contents to be shown on second input depends on choice selected on the first box and the the contents on the 3rd input box depends on the previous 2 choices.

the data to be put on this select boxes is represented as a JSON tree and I have one endpoint to query for it.

I know this is quite possible with javascript but I am thinking if there is a way to achieve it using thymeleaf it would realy help me develop with speed

Comment: Thymeleaf is a server-side pre-processor for your HTML. There is no Thymeleaf remaining in the page which gets rendered by the browser. It sounds as if you want Thymeleaf to respond to input provided by the user - but at that point, Thymeleaf has already done its work (unless you make a call back to the server again). If I have misunderstood the question, perhaps you can clarify?

Comment: Thank you I Just wanted to know if it can be possible 
but from the look of  things it isn't